# jupyter notebook is loading old version of package despite updates

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using SunPy in an environment, and have updated in the command line using `conda update sunpy`. According to the command line, I am using the current version (4.13.0). However, when I open jupyter and load a notebook, I get the following:

```
import sunpy as sp
print(sp.__version__)
3.1.7
```

I've checked to make sure that sunpy was updated in the right folder, I used the right command, I was within the environment when I updated, etc. I'm still getting the wrong version, even if I try `%conda install  -c conda-forge sunpy` to update within the jupyter notebook itself (it says it's already up-to-date). Any ideas on how to force it to load the correct version? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try in a cell in a Jupyter notebok where you want to use the current version, `%conda install  -c conda-forge sunpy`. Unless you already tried that where you said " even if I try to update within the jupyter notebook itself". (Always best to specify what you tried in command form.) If you already tried that, then try `%conda install --force  -c conda-forge sunpy`. Running `%conda install  -c conda-forge sunpy` in a notebook gave me `4.0.3` as currently conda is only up to 4.0.3, which is the current stable release, see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sunpy) & https://sunpy.org/.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant that I'd tried -- I'll update the post to reflect that. If I run `%conda install  -c conda-forge sunpy` I get the notification that everything's already up to date; then if I `import sunpy` and print the version, I still get 3.1.7...

Comment: No luck adding in `force`?

Comment: No luck...I really don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me. Not for sunpy but pandas. I executed line by line within nb cell.**

> !pip install pandas==1.3.5
>
> %conda install -c conda-forge pandas
>
> import pandas as pd

Then `pd. __version__`
i get: '1.3.5'